# iOS - UIImage tinting highlight always grey

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, highlight, tint

I have this button where the background colour is white and the image tint is colour x. When selected, I want the colour to swap - bg is x (which I can do easily) but the image tint always is grey (or a darker version of the colour I set). How can I change it?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"House"];
        image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

        [self setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

//

```
- (void)highlight {
    [super highlight];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:HIGHLIGHT_ANIMATION_TIME animations:^{
        self.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }];
}

- (void)unhighlight {
    [super unhighlight];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:HIGHLIGHT_ANIMATION_TIME animations:^{
        self.tintColor = self.colour;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIButton` has many states try:

```
//disable automatically adjust
self.yourButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

[self setImage:colorChangedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the single | mean?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy it means OR